# Dealing with static resources in dev/live environment ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am going to be serving my site files from a site like cdn.mysite.com and will consume them from site like www.mysite.com.  In development I have web projects setup, 1 for CDN and 1 for the actual site (controllers, views, models).

What I would like to do is come up with the most elegant way to go from dev (development fabric) to live (azure) without having to do some elaborate msbuild task.  Is there some common tools or methodologies out there that are for this purpose?